# Return specific nested fields in Elasticsearch Python query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Python 3.9.5/Elasticsearch Python client 7.14

I'm using the Python Elasticsearch library to run queries against an Elasticsearch 7.10 cluster.

I'm trying to return fields from within a nested field, whereas I can only figure out the syntax to return the values from the entire nested field.

Example:

The ES document I'm returning:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "main",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "123",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1000123,
          "org_name" : {
            "data" : "Acme Inc",
            "entityType" : "ORGANIZATION"
          }
        }
      }
     ]
```

Right now my Python code looks like this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
client = Elasticsearch()

response = client.search(
    index="main",
    body={
          "the ES query"
          }
)
for hit in response['hits']['hits']:
    print(hit['_source']['id'], hit['_source']['org_name'])
```

which returns:

```
1000123 {'data': 'Acme Inc', 'entityType': 'ORGANIZATION'}
```

But what I need to return is:

Either:

```
 1000123 'data': 'Acme Inc'
```

which I can't figure out the syntax for to modify `['org_name']` in the `print` line of the Python code.

Or even better, if possible:

```
1000123 'org_name': 'Acme Inc'
```

The single quotes around `org_name` are of no significance, so it doesn't matter if they are there or not in the response, whichever is achievable the most efficiently is fine with me.

I have reviewed all the examples in the docs for this ES library, and none of them seem to address this.

Comment: Wat ? `print(hit['_source']['id'], {'org_name': hit['_source']['org_name']['data']})` ??

Comment: A-ha, yes that does work!  I couldn't get it to work with the variations I tried!  Please add as an answer and I will mark as answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if this would work for you:
Can you try printing this and tell me what's the result:

```
print(hit['_source']['id'], {'org_name': hit['_source']['org_name']['data']})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).